# visa and passport

Tags: working-visas, passport, legal, thailand

I was working in Thailand, I had some problems at my home so I resigned at the company, the employer said he is not accepting my resignation and is not cancelling my visa or work permit either. They kept my passport (old one which had all my visas and shows my travel history) which they have still not returned to me.

I want to go back to take some action against them but I want to go on my own visa.

I want to know how can I figure out if they have cancelled my work permit and visa to Thailand? What way can I confirm if they have or have not cancelled my work permit and visa?

Comment: Related: [one](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/8784/my-employer-is-holding-my-passport), [two](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/8771/visa-cancellation-when-you-quit-your-job-in-thailand). Interestingly, most of the recent questions tagged [tag:thailand] are about companies who hold their employees' passports. I'm wondering, who on Earth would surrender their passport to anyone, except the police or Immigration officers.

Comment: @bytebuster Indeed,No one can ever surrender their passport to any employer but you have to give your passport for visa renewals,to apply visa etc and the company can trick you many ways.I am sorry to say that you on Earth failed to understand the situation.

Comment: I see your situation with compassion and I hope you can resolve it quickly. Nonetheless, knowing the problem, I'm afraid there will be no other answer than for the linked questions: call your embassy, get a temporary travel document to get back home, make a new passport. And try not to fall for tricks the next time.

Comment: Report your passport stolen and tell the authorities, you know who stole it.

Comment: OP needs to confirm, but I think @iliac has a current passport and has left the country. The ex-employer has an old passport which contains a Thai visa and work permit. OP is trying to determine whether the visa and work permit are still valid in order to return to Thailand and  possibly retrieve the old passport.